# jquery show the sum total when checkbox is checked

Tags: jquery

I am showing the total of the checkbox values when certain checkboxes are checked. Its working fine. I need to show all the checkbox values totals on page load, irrelevant if its checked or not. As of now its just showing the total when a checkbox is checked. Anyone to help me.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

<title> Calc</title>

<script type='text/javascript'>
$(function() {
    $(".tot_amount").click(function(event) {
        var total = 0;
        $(".tot_amount:checked").each(function() {
            total += parseInt($(this).val());
        });
        $("#tot_amount").val(sum.toFixed(3));

        if (total == 0) {
            $('#total1').val('');
        } else {
            $('#total1').val(total);
        }
    });

});
</script>

</head>

<body>
<table border="1">
<tr><td>10<input type="checkbox" class="tot_amount" value="10"></td></tr>
<tr><td>20<input type="checkbox" class="tot_amount" value="20"></td></tr>
<tr><td>30<input type="checkbox" class="tot_amount" value="30"></td></tr>
<tr><td>40<input type="checkbox" class="tot_amount" value="40"></td></tr>
<tr><td>50<input type="checkbox" class="tot_amount" value="50"></td></tr>
<tr><td>60<input type="checkbox" class="tot_amount" value="60"></td></tr>
<tr><td>70<input type="checkbox" class="tot_amount" value="70"></td></tr>

<tr><td>Total<input type="text" id="total1" readonly></td></tr>
</table>

</body>
```

@ Ali... its working but i have a small issue. Let me explain. First of all iam not able to comment on your section. when i click add comment nothing is happening so iam adding my comment here. Its all working. On page load its showing the totals, and when i check any checkboxes its showing the sum. Its all fine. But i need one more function here. If i uncheck all the checkboxes also it should show the whole total as in page load. How will in achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

Create a method

```
function getTotal(isInit) {

  var total = 0;
  var selector = isInit ? ".tot_amount" : ".tot_amount:checked";
  $(selector).each(function() {
    total += parseInt($(this).val());
  });
  if (total == 0) {
    $('#total1').val('');
  } else {
    $('#total1').val(total);
  }

}
```

Then call it from both click and load event

Like this

```
$(function() {
  $(".tot_amount").click(function(event) {
    getTotal();
  });
  getTotal(true);
});
```

<kbd>**[`DEMO`](https://jsfiddle.net/aiubian/bxpt805s/)**</kbd>

Comment: wrong, as OP said- `values totals on page load, irrelevant if its checked or not`.

Comment: `i need to show all the checkbox values totals on page load, irrelevant if its checked or not.` what am i doing wrong ?

Comment: first- its totaling only to checked elements (as OP said irrelevant to checked)
second- in your answer `sum.toFixed(3)` `sum` is not defined. therefore it will not work.
Sorry if I misunderstood the question?

Comment: did you check my fiddle ? @Manoz

Answer (score 2):

i think you need the pre-total of all values. write in

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var preTotal=0;

$(".tot_amount").each(function() {
   preTotal+=parseInt($(this).attr("value"));
});

});
```

for on page ready

Answer (score 2):

```js
function getTotal(objSelector)
{
    var total = 0;
    objSelector.each(function () {
        total += parseInt($(this).val());
    });
    $("#tot_amount").val(total.toFixed(3));
    if (total == 0) {
        $('#total1').val('');
    } else {
        $('#total1').val(total);
    }
}
$(document).ready(function () {
    getTotal($(".tot_amount"));
    $(".tot_amount").change(function (event) {
        getTotal($(".tot_amount:checked"));
    });

});
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
        <title>Calc</title>
        
    </head>
    <body>
        <table border="1">
            <tr><td>10<input type="checkbox" class="tot_amount" value="10"></td></tr>
            <tr><td>20<input type="checkbox" class="tot_amount" value="20"></td></tr>
            <tr><td>30<input type="checkbox" class="tot_amount" value="30"></td></tr>
            <tr><td>40<input type="checkbox" class="tot_amount" value="40"></td></tr>
            <tr><td>50<input type="checkbox" class="tot_amount" value="50"></td></tr>
            <tr><td>60<input type="checkbox" class="tot_amount" value="60"></td></tr>
            <tr><td>70<input type="checkbox" class="tot_amount" value="70"></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Total<input type="text" id="total1" readonly></td></tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It works as per your need.
You can run above code here.

Answer (score 1):

Check out my [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/9g56gm8z/7/)  . It is as per your requirment

```
$(function(){ 
$(".tot_amount").click(function(event) {
var total = 0;
$(".tot_amount:checked").each(function() {
total += parseInt($(this).val());
});
    //$("#tot_amount").val(sum.toFixed(3));

$('#total1').val(total);

});

});

$(document).ready(function () {
var total2=0;
    $(".tot_amount").each(function() {
total2 += parseInt($(this).val());

});


$('#total1').val(total2);
});
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/9g56gm8z/7/)