# Using jquery showing the sum total of records

Tags: jquery

I am showing the total of the checkbox values when certain checkboxes are checked. Its working fine. I need to show all the checkbox values totals on page load, irrelevant if its checked or not. That is also working fine. But at the last if i uncheck all the checkboxes also it should show the whole checkbox value totals.. How will i achieve that?

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

<title> Calc</title>

<script type='text/javascript'>
function getTotal(objSelector)
{
    var total = 0;
    objSelector.each(function () {
        total += parseInt($(this).val());
    });
    $("#tot_amount").val(total.toFixed(3));
    if (total == 0) {
        $('#total1').val('');
    } else {
        $('#total1').val(total);
    }
}
$(document).ready(function () {
    getTotal($(".tot_amount"));
    $(".tot_amount").change(function (event) {
        getTotal($(".tot_amount:checked"));
    });

});
</script>

</head>

<body>
<table border="1">
<tr><td>10<input type="checkbox" class="tot_amount" value="10"></td></tr>
<tr><td>20<input type="checkbox" class="tot_amount" value="20"></td></tr>
<tr><td>30<input type="checkbox" class="tot_amount" value="30"></td></tr>
<tr><td>40<input type="checkbox" class="tot_amount" value="40"></td></tr>
<tr><td>50<input type="checkbox" class="tot_amount" value="50"></td></tr>
<tr><td>60<input type="checkbox" class="tot_amount" value="60"></td></tr>
<tr><td>70<input type="checkbox" class="tot_amount" value="70"></td></tr>

<tr><td>Total<input type="text" id="total1" readonly></td></tr>
</table>

</body>
```

Comment: please dont make different posts for same question ,, you could have asked same thing by editing your own question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34735834/jquery-show-the-sum-total-when-checkbox-is-checked/34736130#34736130

Answer (score 3):

Try like this

```
if($(".tot_amount:checked").length == 0){
  getTotal($(".tot_amount"));
}
```

Full code

```
$(".tot_amount").change(function (event) {

    if($(".tot_amount:checked").length == 0){
      getTotal($(".tot_amount"));
    }
    else 
     getTotal($(".tot_amount:checked"));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/9g56gm8z/9/) as per your requirement ...check out the [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/9g56gm8z/9/) .

```
$(function(){ 
$(".tot_amount").click(function(event) {
var total = 0;
$(".tot_amount:checked").each(function() {
total += parseInt($(this).val());
});
    //$("#tot_amount").val(sum.toFixed(3));
if($(".tot_amount:checked").length == 0){

var total2=0;
     $(".tot_amount").each(function() {
total2 += parseInt($(this).val());

});


$('#total1').val(total2);
}else
{
$('#total1').val(total);
}


});

});

$(document).ready(function () {
var total2=0;
    $(".tot_amount").each(function() {
total2 += parseInt($(this).val());

});


$('#total1').val(total2);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this part:

```
$(".tot_amount").change(function (event) {
    getTotal($(".tot_amount:checked"));
});
```

You should check the amount of checked elements

e.g.

```
$(".tot_amount").change(function (event) {
    if($('.tot_amount').length === 0) {
       getTotal($('.tot_amount'));
    } else {
       getTotal($(".tot_amount:checked"));
    }
});
```